# Asp.Net control Initial Value Not Display after 1st run

Tags: asp.net

I encounter a weird problem when I am run the app via F5 or View In Browser.  When I run the following page for the first time,  "Hello" is shown on the textbox.  Clicked on the 'Click Me' button, the text is changed to "Clicked!".  That's fine.  Close the brower and run F5 (or View in Browser) again, the Textbox shows "Clicked!".  It doesn't display the initial value anymore.  I see this problem on IE6 (and thatis the only option for my employer), but not on FF3.6 nor Googgle Chrome 4.x.  I thought it could be related ViewState.  But, the problem persists after ViewState is disable.

Any idea or hint on what went wrong?

Default.aspx File below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
    <div>    
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Click Me" EnableViewState="false" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="Hello" EnableViewState="false" ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs File below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "Clicked!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The text being shown in TextBox1 is being cached by the browser, so essentially it's (IE6) not making a request to the server whenever you refresh the page. You'll note that when you press F5 the browser prompts you:

[image: IE6 warning about resending information]

This means that when you press F5 or Refresh, the browser is performing the post-back for you which is triggering the `Button1_Click` method and thus causing TextBox1 to contain "*Clicked!*".

I'm not quite sure how you're encountering the:

> Close the brower and run F5 (or View in Browser) again, the Textbox shows "Clicked!"

issue as I can't get IE6 to do that. A possible solution is to  put some cache constraints into the headers you send so that the browser won't store anything in its cache, which should stop this from being a problem.